# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException, but it does exist?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

im writing a programm with Spring MVC and Hibernate and im trying to list all the members of a table, but i keep getting this error `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'patient0_.doctor_idStaffMember' in 'field list'` even tought i do have that column in my DB.

**StaffMember**

```
package com.carloscortina.demo.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name="StaffMember")
public class StaffMember implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4402030728393694289L;
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
    private String cellPhone;
    private String professionalNumber;
    private Set<Patient> patients; 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="idStaffMember")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3,max=20)
    @Column(name="Name")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3,max=20)
    @Column(name="lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name="phone")
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Column(name="cellPhone")
    public String getCellPhone() {
        return cellPhone;
    }
    public void setCellPhone(String cellPhone) {
        this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
    }

    @Column(name="ProfessionalNumber")
    public String getProfessionalNumber() {
        return professionalNumber;
    }
    public void setProfessionalNumber(String professionalNumber) {
        this.professionalNumber = professionalNumber;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="idPatient")
    public Set<Patient> getPatients() {
        return patients;
    }
    public void setPatients(Set<Patient> patients) {
        this.patients = patients;
    }

}
```

**Patient**

```
package com.carloscortina.demo.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;

@Entity
@Table(name="Patient")
public class Patient implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9026423808843575752L;
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    private String fatherLastName;
    private String motherLastName;
    private String curp;
    private String nickname;
    private String sex;
    private Date birthday;
    private String notes;
    private boolean active;
    private StaffMember doctor;
    private Timestamp addedDate;
    private Set<Relative> relatives;

    public Patient() {
        super();
        this.id = 0;
        this.firstName = "";
        this.secondName = "";
        this.fatherLastName = "";
        this.motherLastName = "";
        this.curp = "";
        this.nickname = "";
        this.sex = "";
        this.birthday = null;
        this.notes = "";
        this.active = false;
        this.doctor = null;
        this.addedDate = null;
    }

    public Patient(int id, String firstName, String secondName,
            String fatherLastName, String motherLastName, String curp,
            String nickname, String sex, Date birthday, String notes,
            boolean active, StaffMember doctor, Timestamp addedDate) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.fatherLastName = fatherLastName;
        this.motherLastName = motherLastName;
        this.curp = curp;
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.active = active;
        this.doctor = doctor;
        this.addedDate = addedDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="idPatient")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    @Size(min=3,max=45)
    @Column(name="FirstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the secondName
     */
    @Size(min=3,max=45)
    @Column(name="SecondName")
    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }

    /**
     * @param secondName the secondName to set
     */
    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fatherLastName
     */
    @Size(min=3,max=45)
    @Column(name="FatherLastName")
    public String getFatherLastName() {
        return fatherLastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param fatherLastName the fatherLastName to set
     */
    public void setFatherLastName(String fatherLastName) {
        this.fatherLastName = fatherLastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the motherLastName
     */
    @Size(min=3,max=45)
    @Column(name="MotherLastName")
    public String getMotherLastName() {
        return motherLastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param motherLastName the motherLastName to set
     */
    public void setMotherLastName(String motherLastName) {
        this.motherLastName = motherLastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the curp
     */
    @Size(min=18,max=18)
    @Column(name="curp")
    public String getCurp() {
        return curp;
    }

    /**
     * @param curp the curp to set
     */
    public void setCurp(String curp) {
        this.curp = curp;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nickname
     */
    @Size(min=1,max=45)
    @Column(name="NickName")
    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    /**
     * @param nickname the nickname to set
     */
    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the sex
     */
    @Size(min=8,max=9)
    @Column(name="Sex")
    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    /**
     * @param sex the sex to set
     */
    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    /**
     * @return the birthday
     */
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="Birthday")
    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    /**
     * @param birthday the birthday to set
     */
    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    /**
     * @return the notes
     */
    @Column(name="Notes")
    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    /**
     * @param notes the notes to set
     */
    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    /**
     * @return the active
     */
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="Active")
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    /**
     * @param active the active to set
     */
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    /**
     * @return the doctor
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    public StaffMember getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

    /**
     * @param doctor the doctor to set
     */
    public void setDoctor(StaffMember doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }

    /**
     * @return the addedDate
     */
    public Timestamp getAddedDate() {
        return addedDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param addedDate the addedDate to set
     */
    public void setAddedDate(Timestamp addedDate) {
        this.addedDate = addedDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the relatives
     */
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="idPatient")
    public Set<Relative> getRelatives() {
        return relatives;
    }

    /**
     * @param relatives the relatives to set
     */
    public void setRelatives(Set<Relative> relatives) {
        this.relatives = relatives;
    }





}
```

**The Query**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Patient> getPatients() {
        return ( getSession().createQuery("from Patient").list());
    }
```

**Table Patient**

[image]

**Table StaffMember**

[image]

Could some explain me whats the problem and how can i solve it?

thanks in advance.

**The Error**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/demo] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'patient0_.doctor_idStaffMember' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at com.carloscortina.demo.dao.HbnPatientDao.getPatients(HbnPatientDao.java:33)
    at com.carloscortina.demo.service.PatientServiceImp.getPatients(PatientServiceImp.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy36.getPatients(Unknown Source)
    at com.carloscortina.demo.controller.PatientsController.listAllPatients(PatientsController.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Err, no, you don't have any `doctor_idStaffMember` column in the patient table.

Comment: i tought it refered to the field doctor at te patient table and the idstaffmember at the staffmember table.
also im not pretty sure about the SQL im runnign i mean that all i hace, i use the createquery(from patient).list()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is wrong. It seems like you want a one-to-many bidirectional association between Patient and StaffMember, mapped by the column `Patient.idDoctor`. Here's how you have implemented it:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="idPatient")
public Set<Patient> getPatients() {
    return patients;
}
...
@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
public StaffMember getDoctor() {
    return doctor;
}
```

This creates two unrelated associations, because in a bidirectional association, one side (the many side, in this case) MUST have a `mappedBy` attribute.

So, you created a OneToMany association, telling Hibernate that the `idPatient` column in Patient is a foreign key to StaffMember (which is wrong).

And you created an unrelated ManyToOne association between Patient and StaffMember, without telling Hibernate which column is used to map the association. Hibernate thus uses the default column name, which is `doctor_idStaffMember`, which doesn't exist.

Here's how a bidirectional association using `idDoctor` as a foreign key must be mapped:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "doctor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Patient> getPatients() {
    return patients;
}
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idDoctor")
public StaffMember getDoctor() {
    return doctor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i learned a lot of your answer. I didnt fully grasp the oncept of mappedby, but i will check the docs.